# Can't get jQuery Shiner plugin to work

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this plugin](http://pixelentity.com/previews/components/shiner/) to add a `shine effect` on some elements, but i can't get it to work, there's no documentation either.

This is what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/iaezzy/33cwq8cx/

```
$("h1").peShiner({api:true, paused:true, reverse:true,repeat:1});
```

Comment: So, have you tried the steps ? What was the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this plugin doesn't work on text, only on images.

Nevertheless, neither jsfiddle or SO snippets seem to work too. The only way I got this to work was downloading the files and creating a small sample in my localhost:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.pixelentity.shiner.min.js"></script>
<style>
body { background: black; color:green; }
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".peShiner").peShiner({hover:true,glow:0,duration:3});
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="peShiner">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://blog.reegle.info/wp-content/uploads/postit/small_sun.gif"/></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can download the js files from the page source. Perhaps it's something due to jquery's version, but even then I could not manage to include the js from their source page here, on SO snippet.